# Why doesn't VkPhysicalDeviceVulkan{11|12}Properties contain valid data on Vulkan 1.2?

Tags: vulkan

When using the function `vkGetPhysicalDeviceProperties2` I pass a `VkPhysicalDeviceProperties2` struct with a `VkPhysicalDeviceVulkan11Properties` and `VkPhysicalDeviceVulkan12Properties` in the pNext chain. However, after calling the function, only the `vkGetPhysicalDeviceProperties2` contains valid data, the other structures in the chain contain undefined data.

When reviewing the spec, I noticed the comment about other structures [Vulkan11](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VkPhysicalDeviceVulkan11Properties) and [Vulkan12](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VkPhysicalDeviceVulkan12Properties) structures are supposed to encompass. When replacing them with their corresponding "smaller" structures and adding them to the chain. I do get valid data, which seems even stranger since I don't see what's preventing Vulkan from using the larger structures in the first place.

Note: Validation layers are silent

Info:

- Vulkan SDK: 1.2.141.0
- Nvidia Driver: 446.14
- GPU GeForce GTX 1060 with Max-Q Design
- OS: Windows 10.0.18363
- Compiler: Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.26.28806 for x64

Relevant Code:

```
StaticArray<char const *, 1> const RequiredInstanceLayers{
    "VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation",
};
StaticArray<char const *, 3> const RequiredInstanceExtensions{
    VK_KHR_SURFACE_EXTENSION_NAME,
    VK_EXT_DEBUG_UTILS_EXTENSION_NAME,
    VK_KHR_WIN32_SURFACE_EXTENSION_NAME,
};
VkApplicationInfo ApplicationInfo;
ApplicationInfo.sType              = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_APPLICATION_INFO;
ApplicationInfo.pNext              = nullptr;
ApplicationInfo.pApplicationName   = "Application";
ApplicationInfo.applicationVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0, 0);
ApplicationInfo.pEngineName        = "Engine";
ApplicationInfo.engineVersion      = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0, 0);
ApplicationInfo.apiVersion         = VK_API_VERSION_1_2;
VkInstanceCreateInfo InstanceCreateInfo;
InstanceCreateInfo.sType                   = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO;
InstanceCreateInfo.pNext                   = nullptr;
InstanceCreateInfo.flags                   = 0;
InstanceCreateInfo.pApplicationInfo        = &ApplicationInfo;
InstanceCreateInfo.enabledLayerCount       = RequiredInstanceLayers.length;
InstanceCreateInfo.ppEnabledLayerNames     = RequiredInstanceLayers.data;
InstanceCreateInfo.enabledExtensionCount   = RequiredInstanceExtensions.length;
InstanceCreateInfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames = RequiredInstanceExtensions.data;
vkCreateInstance(&InstanceCreateInfo, nullptr, &m_instance);

Uint32 physical_device_count;
vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices(m_instance, &physical_device_count, nullptr);
m_available_physical_devices.Create(m_allocator, physical_device_count);
vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices(m_instance, &physical_device_count, m_available_physical_devices.beg);

for (auto it = m_available_physical_devices.beg; it != m_available_physical_devices.end; ++it)
{
    { // Test 1
        VkPhysicalDeviceProperties2 Properties2;
        VkPhysicalDeviceVulkan11Properties Vulkan11Properties;
        VkPhysicalDeviceVulkan12Properties Vulkan12Properties;
        Properties2.sType        = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_PROPERTIES_2;
        Vulkan11Properties.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_VULKAN_1_1_PROPERTIES;
        Vulkan12Properties.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_VULKAN_1_2_PROPERTIES;
        Properties2.pNext        = &Vulkan11Properties;
        Vulkan11Properties.pNext = &Vulkan12Properties;
        Vulkan12Properties.pNext = nullptr;
        vkGetPhysicalDeviceProperties2(*it, &Properties2); // only Properties2 is filled out
        // Vulkan11Properties and Vulkan12Properties contain undefined data
    }
    { // Test 2
        VkPhysicalDeviceProperties2                   Properties2;
        VkPhysicalDeviceDriverProperties              DriverProperties;
        VkPhysicalDeviceFloatControlsProperties       FloatControlsProperties;
        VkPhysicalDeviceDescriptorIndexingProperties  DescriptorIndexingProperties;
        VkPhysicalDeviceDepthStencilResolveProperties DepthStencilResolveProperties;
        VkPhysicalDeviceSamplerFilterMinmaxProperties SamplerFilterMinmaxProperties;
        VkPhysicalDeviceTimelineSemaphoreProperties   TimelineSemaphoreProperties;
        VkPhysicalDeviceIDProperties                  IDProperties;
        VkPhysicalDeviceSubgroupProperties            SubgroupProperties;
        VkPhysicalDevicePointClippingProperties       PointClippingProperties;
        VkPhysicalDeviceMultiviewProperties           MultiviewProperties;
        VkPhysicalDeviceProtectedMemoryProperties     ProtectedMemoryProperties;
        VkPhysicalDeviceMaintenance3Properties        Maintenance3Properties;
        Properties2.sType                   = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_PROPERTIES_2;
        DriverProperties.sType              = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_DRIVER_PROPERTIES;
        FloatControlsProperties.sType       = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_FLOAT_CONTROLS_PROPERTIES;
        DescriptorIndexingProperties.sType  = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR_INDEXING_PROPERTIES;
        DepthStencilResolveProperties.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_DEPTH_STENCIL_RESOLVE_PROPERTIES;
        SamplerFilterMinmaxProperties.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_SAMPLER_FILTER_MINMAX_PROPERTIES;
        TimelineSemaphoreProperties.sType   = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_TIMELINE_SEMAPHORE_PROPERTIES;
        IDProperties.sType                  = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_ID_PROPERTIES;
        SubgroupProperties.sType            = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_SUBGROUP_PROPERTIES;
        PointClippingProperties.sType       = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_POINT_CLIPPING_PROPERTIES;
        MultiviewProperties.sType           = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_MULTIVIEW_PROPERTIES;
        ProtectedMemoryProperties.sType     = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_PROTECTED_MEMORY_PROPERTIES;
        Maintenance3Properties.sType        = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_MAINTENANCE_3_PROPERTIES;
        Properties2.pNext                   = &DriverProperties;
        DriverProperties.pNext              = &FloatControlsProperties;
        FloatControlsProperties.pNext       = &DescriptorIndexingProperties;
        DescriptorIndexingProperties.pNext  = &DepthStencilResolveProperties;
        DepthStencilResolveProperties.pNext = &SamplerFilterMinmaxProperties;
        SamplerFilterMinmaxProperties.pNext = &TimelineSemaphoreProperties;
        TimelineSemaphoreProperties.pNext   = &IDProperties;
        IDProperties.pNext                  = &SubgroupProperties;
        SubgroupProperties.pNext            = &PointClippingProperties;
        PointClippingProperties.pNext       = &MultiviewProperties;
        MultiviewProperties.pNext           = &ProtectedMemoryProperties;
        ProtectedMemoryProperties.pNext     = &Maintenance3Properties;
        Maintenance3Properties.pNext        = nullptr;
        vkGetPhysicalDeviceProperties2(*it, &Properties2); // every structure is filled out
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nvidia 446.14 drivers are Vulkan 1.1. `VkPhysicalDeviceVulkan11Properties` and `VkPhysicalDeviceVulkan12Properties` both require Vulkan 1.2.

The `struct` are untouched, because the spec says:

> Any component of the implementation (the loader, any enabled layers, and drivers) **must** skip over, without processing (other than reading the `sType` and `pNext` members) any extending structures in the chain not defined by core versions or extensions supported by that component.

On the other hand it is not valid usage:

> Each structure present in the `pNext` chain **must** be defined at runtime either by a core version which is supported, or by an extension which is enabled.

So Validation layers should ideally be catching this. You should report this at [KhronosGroup/Vulkan-ValidationLayers](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-ValidationLayers/issues). The problem seems to be the layers check indiscriminately of what version it is, and what extensions are enabled.

Comment: Thanks, I probably should've updated my driver's before asking, but thanks for the answer.